# Accessing the Google Api to get a file list with valid access and Refresh tokens

Tags: php, get, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I am using an [Oauth class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html) for an app to get access to the Google drive API, I have both refresh and access tokens and now all I need to get the ball rolling is to set the parameters for the request.

My issue is that I cannot seem to find the parameters needed to get the appropriate response, I have looked at the OAuth playground and the request sent has three headers `Authorization`,  `Host` And `Content length`.

The class that I am using should handle these headers correctly and I'm pretty sure it is doing something right in that it actually receives the `code` and `access/refresh tokens` correctly.

When I send the request an error from Google is returned;

```
StdClass Object
(
[error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [domain] => global
                        [reason] => authError
                        [message] => Invalid Credentials
                        [locationType] => header
                        [location] => Authorization
                    )
            )
        [code] => 401
        [message] => Invalid Credentials
    )
)
```

This surely indicates invalid credentials? but if I have just recieved the "fresh" access tokens and refresh tokens this should surely be OK? here is the request I am sending (as per the OAuth classes methods).

```
$row = $this->docs_auth->row();

$this->client                = new oauth_client_class;
$this->client->server        = 'Google';
$this->client->redirect_uri  = 'https://localhost/p4a/applications/reflex_application/index.php';
$this->client->debug         = true;
$this->client->client_id     = REFLEX_GOOGLE_CLIENT;
$this->client->client_secret = REFLEX_GOOGLE_SECRET;
$this->client->access_token  = $row['access_token'];
$this->client->refresh_token = $row['refresh_token'];


$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files';

$Values = array(
    'access_token'  => $this->client->access_token,
    'client_id'     => $this->client->client_id,
    'client_secret' => $this->client->client_secret
);
/*
 * Request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files
 * $values = the values sent in the request
 * $folder = the response returned from Google.
 */

$this->client->callAPI($url, 'GET', $values, array(
    'FailOnAccessError' => false
), $folder);


$this->field->setValue(print_r($folder, true));
```

So my question is, what are the correct parameters to be sent to Google to get the folder and file list and what are the headers required for the request (I don't want to edit the class too much but have needed to already).

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving this for a few months and coming back to it I finally got the method you were looking for, although i used Google's own class:

The method is roughly the same;

First call the class with `$this->client = new Google_Client();`

Then set all the metadata required to get the response for a specific client, set the scopes and set the access type:

```
    // Get your credentials from the APIs Console
    $this->client->setClientId($this->client_id);
    $this->client->setClientSecret($this->client_secret);
    $this->client->setRedirectUri($this->redirect_uri);
    $this->client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive ','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file' ));
        $this->client->setAccessType("offline");
```

Then finally get your stored access token (in database or stored in session) and use `Google_DriveService($this->client)` and these functions within the class to perform the listing of files:

```
try{

            $json = json_encode($this->loadAccessTokenFromDB());

            $this->client->setAccessToken($json);
            $this->client->setUseObjects(true);
            $service = new Google_DriveService($this->client);

            $parameters = array();
            $parameters['q'] = " FullText contains '" . $searchString . "'";
            $files = $service->files->listFiles($parameters);
            $ourfiles = $files->getItems();

            $fileArray = array();

            foreach ( $ourfiles as $file )
            {
                $fileArray[] = array(
                        'title'          => $file->getTitle(),
                        'id'             => $file->getID(),
                        'created'        => $file->getCreatedDate(),
                        'embedlink'      => $file->getEmbedLink(),
                        'exportlinks'    => $file->getExportLinks(),
                        'thumblink'      => $file->getThumbnailLink(),
                        'mimeType'       => $file->getMimeType(),
                        'webContentLink' => $file->getWebContentLink(),
                        'alternateLink'  => $file->getAlternateLink(),
                        'permissions'    => $file->getUserPermission()
                );
            }
            //$this->mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
            $this->documents->load($fileArray);
            if ($fileArray["id"] !== "")
            {
                $this->documents->firstRow();

                return;
            }
        } catch(Google_AuthException $e) {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
        return;
    }
```

I was also doing testing on search strings that could be used, from what i managed to get tested, the string must be a string with no breaks and it will search for anything that contains that specific string of characters, e.g.

`foo` would give documents containing words like: `foo` `foobar` etc. but wouldent find `foo bar` so you must be careful, ideally you should be looking to have a specific unique string to search for if it is specific docs for a user or anything,

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the link you posted, and the example the original class creator wrote, you may to call a Initialize() on the class before making the callAPI() call.

Here is the example he uses:

```
if(($success = $client->Initialize()))
{
    if(($success = $client->Process()))
    {
        if(strlen($client->authorization_error))
        {
            $client->error = $client->authorization_error;
            $success = false;
        }
        elseif(strlen($client->access_token))
        {
            $success = $client->CallAPI(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo',
                'GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
        }
    }
    $success = $client->Finalize($success);
}
```

Comment: i already called the initialize and process methods previously to get the access and refresh tokens, I'm just unsure on the parameters required to get the file list, although by the looks of what you have shown, there are no parameters being sent at all :S.